# Can Two Components in a UML Component Diagram Have Mutual Provide and Require Interfaces?

Tags: component-diagram

I'm currently designing a system using UML component diagrams and I've encountered a scenario that has left me a bit puzzled. In my design, I have two components that are seemingly interdependent, meaning each component provides an interface that the other requires. This has led me to wonder about the feasibility and correctness of this design approach within the UML specification and best practices in software architecture.

Specifically, my question is:

Is it possible and correct according to UML specifications for two components to both provide and require interfaces from each other?